# Display image in android application

Tags: android

Firstly I don't know what it is called but i want to know how and what it is. The thing is the video or image that we usually find on top of the page when we open an application page to download it from play store.I 'am currently doing a project and i want to include that design in my application.Please help me on how to do it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly the thing you are looking for could be [Collapsing Toolbar Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html), and here is [nice example of it](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/).

Also you can achieve UI effect called Parallax Scroll using some external libs like [ParallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) and [android-parallax-listview](https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-listview).

Also here is an example of Collapsing Toolbar Layout from [CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout):

[image]

Comment: Sir, as i can see there is beautifully formatted text below that Collapsing tool bar layout. I 'am a beginner and i know only  one to format like that using "fromHtml" attribute and convert it to string.Sir, i want to know if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: @Midhun thanks, this text block looks like a CardView with several  TextViews. You can raise a separate issue for this question, and this one could be marked as 'resolved' if your initial question is answered.